# Compare 2 MYSQL Tables and depending on the conditions either insert or update - 1 million record

Tags: mysql

Here is Mysql tables `dumpdata_temp` and `dumpdata`. I am trying to INSERT or UPDATE data from the `dumpdata_temp` Mysql TABLE to `dumpdata`.

`dumpdata_temp` is the temporary table which has the Raw data

```
CREATE TABLE  `dumpdata_temp` (
`TEST_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`QTY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`SKU` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`TEST_ID`)
) 

CREATE TABLE  `dumpdata` (
`TEST_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`QTY` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`SKU` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`TEST_ID`)
)
```

I tried with

INSERT INTO `dumpdata` SELECT * FROM `dumpdata_temp`;

```
There are 2 conditions that I am trying to achieved with an IF ELSE
```

1: IF the column SKU in the `dumpdata_temp` file `MATCHES` with the column SKU in the `dumpdata` table THEN UPDATE column `QTY=1` in the database.

2: IF the column SKU in the `dumpdata_temp` file `DOES NOT MATCH` with the column SKU in the `dumpdata` table THEN INSERT that whole row (record) as it is.

Comment: you can use merge statement. which version of mysql you use.

Comment: How on earth can those PRIMAY KEY statements work :)

Comment: @RahulBiswas there is no MErge in mysql?

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry it was a typo.. updated now